# Play framework router issue in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, playframework

I'm having trouble getting my @Get annotations to work in Tomcat. I'm only having this issue when deploying the actual WAR file to my Tomcat prod server but everything works when I run it using `play run`

```
http://localhost:8080/test/hello/world/ -- routes -- WORKS
GET     /hello/world/?                   Foo.greet

http://localhost:8080/test/hello/john/ -- annotated using router -- DOESN'T WORK
@Get("/hello/john/?")
public static void greet() {
 System.out.println("Hello!");
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `@Get` instead of the routes file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a module [like this](http://www.playframework.org/modules/router-head/home). I've personally had many issues with some modules when trying to run them in slightly modified environments (like Heroku), so most likely it's a module problem (which means you won't fix it without hacking into the module).

If you are using the module I linked before, your best chance is to open a bug report for it [here](https://github.com/digiPlant/play-router-annotations/issues) so the author can patch it.

I would also advise using the *routes* file. It decouples routes from code, which is handy when refactoring and *prettier* from the point of view of design. It also allows for a few extra tricks (as it accepts flow-control structures) which may be harder to pull using annotations.

Comment: Yup, I'm using the router module. Actually trying to get in touch with the author before I submit an issue due to the fact that this may just be a problem with my setup.